# Is there a simple proof that $BS(m,n)$ is residually finite when $n | m$ or $m | n$?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

In their orginal paper, [SOME TWO-GENERATOR ONE-RELATOR
NON-HOPFIAN GROUPS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1962-68-03/S0002-9904-1962-10745-9/S0002-9904-1962-10745-9.pdf) , G. Baumslag and D. Solitar mention that, if $n$ or $m$ divides the other, then $BS(m,n)$ is residually finite, but they do not give a proof of this fact.

Are you aware of a simple proof of this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim in the original paper of Baumslag and Solitar is incorrect. The correct result, due to Meskin, *Nonresidually finite one-relator groups*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 164 (1972), 105-114 ([open access](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-164-00/S0002-9947-1972-0285589-5/)), is:

**Theorem.**
$BS(m, n)$ is residually finite if and only if either $|m|=1$ or $|n|=1$ or $|m|=|n|$.

In fact, Meskin proves something slightly stronger, where the relator $b^{-1}a^mba^n$ is replaced with $u^{-1}v^muv^n$, where $u$ and $v$ are non-commuting words. Meskin's paper is only 10 pages, so quite accessible (although the proof in Moldavanskii's survey is shorter).

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer because Meskin's proof is, in my opinion, clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a simple proof given in the article [On the residual properties of Baumslag–Solitar groups](https://www-tandfonline-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/doi/full/10.1080/00927872.2018.1424867?scroll=top&needAccess=true&) by
David Moldavanskii.

Comment: This link didn't work for me. However, its on the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3585), and it has a [doi](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2018.1424867).