# How do you prove that $BS(m,n)$ is hopfian when m and n have the same prime factors?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, hopfian

In [SOME TWO-GENERATOR ONE-RELATOR
NON-HOPFIAN GROUPS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1962-68-03/S0002-9904-1962-10745-9/S0002-9904-1962-10745-9.pdf) , the authors say that if $\pi(m) = \pi(n)$ (where $\pi(k)$ is the set of prime factors of $k \in \mathbb{N}$), then every surjective morphism $\phi: G \to G$ is an automorphism, and therefore $G$ is hopfian.

This is absolutely not obvious to me, and I can't prove it. I tried to directly tackle it by trying to prove that $\ker \phi = \{1\}$, but nothing resulted from this. Then I tried to suppose that $\phi$ is not injective and derive a contradiction, but I did not manage to use that $\pi(n) = \pi(m)$ and conclude something. I also tried to prove that, assuming $n > m$, $BS(n,n)$ is a subgroup of $BS(m,n)$ with finite index, thus by [Corollary 2](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-141-00/S0002-9947-1969-0258939-3/S0002-9947-1969-0258939-3.pdf), $BS(m,n)$ is hopfian. But I did not even manage to prove that $BS(n,n)$ is a subgroup and I did not even try to compute the index.

Anybody has an idea on how to proceed to prove this?

Comment: $BS(m, n)$ is Hopfian if $m$ and $n$ have the same prime factors, see Theorem $24$ [here](https://berstein2015.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/residual-finiteness-and-hopfian-groups/). A proof can be found again in the paper by 
David Moldavanski, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384047/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-bsm-n-is-residually-finite-when-n-m-or-m/3384054#3384054).

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, but I can't pinpoint where this fact is proved in Moldavanski's paper?

Comment: I think the idea is to prove residual finiteness, then apply Theorem 21 of the first link in the comment of @DietrichBurde which says that finitely generated, residually finite groups are Hopfian.

Comment: @LeeMosher Unfortunately, it does not seem to be the case: Meskin proved that [$BS(m,n)$ is residually finite iff $|m| = 1$ or $|n| = 1$ or $|m| = |n|$](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-164-00/S0002-9947-1972-0285589-5/). What I wrote is almost a quotation of the paper, so I assume it is what the authors proved when they wrote the paper. It seems that they left it as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: @LeeMosher To insist, $BS(2,4)$ is Hopfian but not residually finite. (And the residual finiteness criterion in the original paper by Baumslag and Solitar was mistaken and corrected by Meskin.) The fact that $BS(m,n)$ is Hopfian whenever $m,n$ have the same set of prime factors seems to be due to Collins and Levin, 1978/1983. The proof seems too much technical to be included as a brief answer here. The first step (using a presentation $\langle t,x|tx^mt^{-1}=t^n\rangle$) is to reduce to an endomorphism mapping $x$ to $x^k$ for some $k$, and then work further.

Comment: OP: It is not true that $BS(n,n)$ occurs as subgroup of finite index in $BS(n,m)$. More precisely, for any two $1\le m,n$ with $m\neq n$, $BS(m,n)$ and $BS(n,n)$ have no isomorphic subgroups of finite index.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out LaurentHayez and YCor.